# Nhibernate: Who is responsible of transaction management in a non web application

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions, data-access-layer, data-access

Well in a web application a unit of work is responsible for the transaction management.

But what about a windows application?

As far as I know the repository is the connector between my data access layer and my business layer.
It hides all the data access stuff from my business layer.

Using this fact let me think of taking all the transaction stuff into the repository.

But I read that having Commit/RollBack methods on the repository is violating the repository's intent.

I ask myself who is responsible for transaction management in a non web application and how do I hide the transaction/Nhibernate stuff from the business layer?

Comment: Ayende has an example app https://github.com/ayende/Effectus

Comment: ok that might be a solotion for win forms ... what about windows services?

Comment: I can describe a pattern I've had success with. It applies if you have a simple "one transaction per operation" model (no nested transactions required) and you're using an IoC container. Would this meet your needs? Basically, when service-layer code decides it's time to "do domain work" it uses the command pattern and an invoker for the command (the invoker is given to the service code by IoC)

Comment: @default.kramer would you be so nice and provide an conrete answer? Using the command pattern is well suited for my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general answer is "Whoever instantiates the `ISession` should dispose of it. If the transaction has not been committed, this is effectively a rollback."

I've had success by using the command pattern to define an operation that I want to perform on a unit of work. Say we have a `Person` entity and one of the things we can do is change a person's name. Let's start with the entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; private set; }

    public virtual void ChangeName(string newName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newName))
        {
            throw new DomainException("Name cannot be empty");
        }

        if (newName.Length > 20)
        {
            throw new DomainException("Name cannot exceed 20 characters");
        }

        this.Name = newName;
    }
}
```

Define a simple POCO Command like this:

```
public class ChangeNameCommand : IDomainCommand
{
    public ChangeNameCommand(int personId, string newName)
    {
        this.PersonId = personId;
        this.NewName = newName;
    }

    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string NewName { get; set; }
}
```

...and a Handler for the command:

```
public class ChangeNameCommandHandler : IHandle<ChangeNameCommand>
{
    ISession session;

    public ChangeNameCommandHandler(ISession session)
    {
        // You could demand an IPersonRepository instead of using the session directly.
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void Handle(ChangeNameCommand command)
    {
        var person = session.Load<Person>(command.PersonId);
        person.ChangeName(command.NewName);
    }
}
```

The goal is that code that exists outside of a Session/Work scope can do something like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    ICommandInvoker invoker;

    public SomeClass(ICommandInvoker invoker)
    {
        this.invoker = invoker;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var command = new ChangeNameCommand(1, "asdf");
        invoker.Invoke(command);
    }
}
```

The invocation of the command implies "do this command on a unit of work." This is what we want to happen when we invoke the command:

1. Begin an IoC nested scope (the "Unit of Work" scope)
2. Start an ISession and Transaction (this is probably implied as part of step 3)
3. Resolve an `IHandle<ChangeNameCommand>` from the IoC scope
4. Pass the command to the handler (the domain does its work)
5. Commit the transaction
6. End the IoC scope (the Unit of Work)

So here's an example using [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) as the IoC container:

```
public class UnitOfWorkInvoker : ICommandInvoker
{
    Autofac.ILifetimeScope scope;

    public UnitOfWorkInvoker(Autofac.ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public void Invoke<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : IDomainCommand
    {
        using (var workScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope("UnitOfWork")) // step 1
        {
            var handler = workScope.Resolve<IHandle<TCommand>>(); // step 3 (implies step 2)
            handler.Handle(command); // step 4

            var session = workScope.Resolve<NHibernate.ISession>();
            session.Transaction.Commit(); // step 5

        } // step 6 - When the "workScope" is disposed, Autofac will dispose the ISession.
          // If an exception was thrown before the commit, the transaction is rolled back.
    }
}
```

Note: The `UnitOfWorkInvoker` I've shown here is violating [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - it is a `UnitOfWorkFactory`, a `UnitOfWork`, and an `Invoker` all in one. In my actual implementation, I broke them out.

Comment: Who was responsible for calling session.SaveOrUpdate? And who is responsible for calling session.Save or session.Update in case you have assigned Ids? I also don't know if it is best to commit the transaction for each command. In a web application it's common to have a single session and transaction per request (preferably lazily loaded/started) and you commit on the end of the request or rollback if any error occurred. Since the transaction is started by whoever created the session, it's also its responsibility to commit or rollback, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Loudenvier - Depending on the application, a "one transaction per command" pattern may not be appropriate. Commands are just one possible way to delineate transaction boundaries. In my example, the UnitOfWorkInvoker implicitly creates the session and transaction by calling `Resolve`, so it is fine that it commits it. Also, laziness could be added easily (assuming Autofac) by asking the DI container for `Lazy<ISession>`.

Comment: I'm too using Lazy<ISession> but with a simpler approach as it is tailor made to web applications. I believe it works pretty much like your own, but it's less sophisticated as I don't require it right now.

What I really didn't understand in your sample was where Save or SaveOrUpdate would be called. The ChangeNameCommandHandler only calls person.ChangeName() but it doesn't Save, Update or SaveOrUpdate it... So I was wondering where you keep track of changed/created entities and call the save... Perhaps the command itself should do it, right?

Comment: @Loudenvier - Note that this question is about _non_-webapps. In a webapp, you would typically use the web request to delineate the transaction boundary. Regarding `SaveOrUpdate`, I don't call it because NH tracks entities loaded and will update the DB automatically, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1380616/644812)

Answer (score 1):

When I use repositories, they are contained within a unit of work. The unit of work tracks changes to the repositories and handles transaction management.

Why would it be valid to use a unit of work to handle transaction management in a web application and not in a windows application? If it's an N-Tier application, your business layer would actually be shared between both.

Comment: I agree with Joel here.  I don't see why it has to be different.  Currently I am using repositories and I pass my IUnitOfWork\ISession into each repository.

Comment: the IUnitOfWork into the repository Oo?!

Comment: well the repository and the unit of work depends on the ISession/IStatelessSession. in the web both share the session within the HttpContext. In non web applications you have to put the session in your own dictionary. Yes and now I flounder ...

Comment: @Rookian, I'm not sure I understand your concern here.

Comment: Well in a web application you have one place for your UoW. In non wep applications you have many places for it (the usages are spreaded), but I think this is just "ok", isn't it?