# NHibernate saving implicitly?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm experiencing some odd behaviour with NHibernate and I don't know if maybe I'm just misunderstanding how sessions and transactions work.

The behaviour is I'm openening a Session, starting a transaction for that session. I then retrieve a collection of objects using the session, manipulate the objects in some way then Commit the transaction. At no point in this process am I calling Save or Update on the session but it is implicitly saving the state of the objects within the session.

Is this appropriate behaviour? I'm using a wrapper for my sessions which is why it always opens and commits the transactions.

Comment: And I presume removing the commit stops them from being saved? Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380581/nhibernate-commit-db-changes-without-explict-call-to-save-or-update

Comment: Yes just tested this and removing the commit stops the items from being saved. Weirdly though I tested this on another object and it doesn't behave the same way...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth yes you are correct...d'oh! I did see that post but only read as far as SaveOrUpdate, I thought he was talking about something different to what I was experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on the Flush, FlushMode and IsDirty. This is common when you manipulate collections.

if you change the items in a collection or change the pointer from one collection to the new collection is Nhibernate scans through IsDirty at the time of the flush.